# Eclipse plugin as new software

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I wrote a plugin for eclipse , the way the user can install me plugin for now is manually add it to eclipse\ Plugin
I would like to give the option to install it as new software
what the way to do it?\

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want to build an update site.  There is an new resource Wizard for creating a project that contains an update site.  Use this wizard and configure the site to add a feature (there's a new plugin project wizard for that, too) that contains your plugin.  To oversimplify, you just deploy the contents of the update site project and provide your users with the url to that location.